# pkcs11 - questions regarding `C_EncryptUpdate/C_EncryptFinal`

Tags: encryption, cryptography, pkcs#11

I'm using `C_EncryptUpdate/C_EncryptFinal` and I don't really understand what is supposed to do `C_EncryptFinal`.

My assumption is that `C_EncryptFinal` is used to add the padding and last block encryption when the size of the buffer to encrypt is not a multiple of the block size.

Am I correct? Shall `C_EncryptFinal` always be called after a `C_EncryptUpdate` loop ?

Comment: Hint: [What does the manual say?](http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/group__SEC__11__8__ENCRYPTION__FUNCTIONS.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure you have all the ciphertext you *should* call `C_EncryptFinal`.

> After calling **C_EncryptInit**, the application can either call **C_Encrypt**
>   to encrypt data  in a single part; or call  **C_EncryptUpdate** zero or
>   more times, followed by  **C_EncryptFinal**, to encrypt data in multiple
>   parts.  The encryption operation is active  until the application uses
>   a call to **C_Encrypt** or **C_EncryptFinal** to actually obtain the  final
>   piece of ciphertext.  To process additional data (in single or
>   multiple parts), the  application must call **C_EncryptInit** again.

You can replace calls to `C_EncryptUpdate` and `C_EncryptFinal` (aka *multiple-part* operation) with single `C_Encrypt` if you have all your plaintext ready in a single buffer (aka *single-part* operation).

(Beware that some mechanisms might support only *single-part* operation, e.g. `CKM_RSA_X_509`)

---

EDIT:

The `C_EncryptFinal` does not necessarily need to return any data (i.e. the returned encrypted data part length in *pulEncryptedPartLen* can be zero).

As you say, the `CKM_AES_CBC` encryption which was fed with block aligned data (via `C_EncryptUpdate`) will *probably* return no encrypted data part after `C_EncryptFinal` for most of the implementations (as they would return the corresponding ciphertext immediately in the `C_EncryptUpdate`).

But there might exist an implementation, which internally buffers this block aligned data without encrypting it (thus returning zero length output data part in `C_EncryptUpdate`) and which then encrypts all the buffered data at once during the `C_EncryptFinal` -- an example might be an implementation backed by a smart card (or a remote host), where it *might* be a good idea to send data in larger chunks (even if the cryptoki itself receives data in a block sized chunks).

PKCS#11 API allows that and you have to handle it correctly (i.e. check returned lengths, shift your destination pointers/update the space available accordingly).

---

Think of it as of a *universal API* which needs to support any imaginable mechanism.